# Trusty Tahr 14.04 update disables SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, upgrade

Ive recently been updating some servers on AWS from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04.

For some updates the SSH Daemon does not appear to start correctly after the final reboot. Although all other service appear to work correctly.

If anyone has been experiencing similar problems or know why this might be happening, that would be great.

thanks

Comment: What runtime level is the daemon set at?

Comment: I expect `/var/log/auth.log` to contain an error message, which can tell us, why it is failing to start.

Comment: Upgrading from one Ubuntu LTS to the next LTS version usually comes with the first point release (x.04.1) which is usually released in august. It is recommended to wait for that.

Comment: Check the run levels associated with with 'sysv-rc-conf'